# Liferay.SearchContainer is undefined

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to use SearchContainer but I have a problem with my javascript file. I'm creating an AUI module and calling `Liferay.SearchContainer.get` method. Unfortunately I'm getting `TypeError: Liferay.SearchContainer is undefined` in browser's console log. What I'm doing wrong?

Here's my js code:

```
AUI.add(
'myModule',
function(A) {
    var Lang = A.Lang;

    var Module = A.Component.create(
        {
            ATTRS: {
                ...
            },

            AUGMENTS: [Liferay.PortletBase],
            EXTENDS: A.Base,
            NAME: 'mymodule',

            prototype: {
                initializer: function(config) {
                    var instance = this;
                    var namespace = instance.NS;
                    var searchContainer = Liferay.SearchContainer.get(namespace + instance.get('searchContainerId'));
                },
                ...
            }
        }
    );
},
'',
{
    requires: ['liferay-portlet-base']
}
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my mistake. SearchContainer was not included in my jsp file. Problem solved.

Comment: Since your component is making use of Liferay.SearchContainer, the good practice is to add the dependency to the requires array, so it is clear that this module needs it. If you add it to your jsp, you're adding an implicit dependency and your module will work depending on the context, so you might run into problems later.